# Call pushViewController from outside class?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7

I'am new to iOS 7. And I'm struggling to call `pushViewController`.

I have `MyCollectionViewController` class which is root controller of `UINavigationController` and `CollectionViewCell` class for customising a collection cell.

In this case I have NO problem to `pushViewController` by using in `MyCollectionViewController`:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSDictionary *product = self.products[indexPath.row];

TXDetailProductController *detailView = [[TXDetailProductController alloc] init];
detailView.product = product;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];

}
```

But I want to do call `pushViewController:detailView` from `CollectionViewCell` class which is included in `MyCollectionViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create delegate methods and define it into the class from You can easily create delegate methods and define it into the class where u have didSelectItemAtIndexPath , and call the delegate methods from CollectionViewCell class.

```
@protocol CollectionViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)pushMethod;

@end
@interface CollectionViewController : UIViewController
{
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)id<CollectionViewDelegate>delegate;
```

and implement the push method in the same class where u have CollectionView like this:

```
-(void)pushMethod
{
TXDetailProductController *detailView = [[TXDetailProductController alloc] init];
detailView.product = product;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
}
```

and call this method easily from CollectionViewCell class.

Comment: Okay, interesting can you show me a code sniped how to call pushMethod from CollectionViewCell. I've tried TXCollectionViewController *cv = [[TXCollectionViewController alloc] init]; and than cv.pushMethod; but no success!

Comment: You need to call by delegate.pushMethod and make delegate to self when come to collection view cell class